# fatal error: QTextStream: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, qt4, codeblocks

I would like try write something in qt4. I began reading a tutorial. 
I tried run simple code from this page: http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/datetime/ and I'm surprised. My the best IDE(code::Blocks, newest version) said me:

> fatal error: QTextStream: No such file or directory

Hmm, interested. I am using Arch Linux if that change something.

Of course I searched /usr catalog and appropriate files are there.

Anyone has idea about this?

Comment: Please, show us your code. There are quite a lot examples on this page.

Comment: Do you use `qmake` & `pro`-files?

Comment: @Lol4t0 Good thinking, the header is probably not found.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, header is not found due to Qt Core lib is not included, but I don't know how to configure build with `code::Blocks`

Comment: @xorgx3 You might want to google how to properly set up code::blocks for qt development. Setting include and lib paths, etc.

Comment: Ohh, hell yea! it was hard to found, but i did it! Answer is here:http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/4537/#msg20094 thanks guy's!

Comment: Using CodeBlock for writing Qt-apps is like using VisualStudio for writing Linux kernel. On Linux is Qt-Creator a way better, as it helps to set-up a Qt-project, run qmake axplicitely, not as a custom/tool shell script, edit UIs and jump from UI-signals directly to code.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu/Debian this will fix your error:

```
 apt-get install qt4-dev-tools
```

(Sorry, I don't know Arch Linux.)

Comment: "Of course I searched /usr catalog and appropriate files are there." - Qt seems to be installed.

Comment: I just had this exact same problem, and that command fixed it for me.    For the record that command doesn't install Qt.   It installs important libraries and header files needed to do Qt related *development*.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017, the `qt4-dev-tools` does not include `qt4-dev`.  On ubuntu 16 or greater you will probably need:

```
apt-get install qt4-dev-tools qt4-make libqt4-dev
```

What is disturbing about this is that `apt-cache search QTextStream` does not list that package, but lists the one with the .so's